# "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected\n what should I fix

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle query as follows but when I make changes to pagination the results are different. what should i pass for my code

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT b.*,
         ROWNUM r__
  FROM (
    select a.KODE_KLAIM,
           a.NO_SS,
           a.LA,
           a.NAMA_TK,
           a.KODE_K,
           (
             select tk.TEM_LAHIR
             from KN.VW_KN_TK tk
             where tk.KODE_K = a.KODE_K and rownum=1
           ) TEM_LAHIR,
           (
             select TO_CHAR(tk.TLAHIR, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
             from KN.VW_KTK tk
             where tk.KODE_K = a.KODE_K
             and rownum=1
           ) TLAHIR
    from PN.KLAIM a
    where nvl(a.STATUS_BATAL,'X') = 'T'
    and A.NOMOR IS NOT NULL
    and A.TIPE_KLAIM = 'JPN01'
  )b
)
where 1 = 1
WHERE ROWNUM < ( ( ? * ? ) + 1 )
WHERE r__ >= ( ( ( ? - 1 ) * ? ) + 1 )
```

but i run this query i have result  ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

You have three `WHERE` clauses at the end (and no `ORDER BY` clause). To make it syntactically valid you could change the second and third `WHERE` clauses to `AND`.

However, you mention pagination so what you probably want is to use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT b.*,
         ROWNUM r__
  FROM (
    select ...
    from   ...
    ORDER BY something
  )b
  WHERE ROWNUM < :page_size * :page_number + 1
)
WHERE r__ >= ( :page_number - 1 ) * :page_size + 1
```

*Note: You can replace the named bind variables with anonymous bind variables if you want.*

Or, if you are using Oracle 12 or later then you can use the `OFFSET x ROWS FETCH FIRST y ROWS ONLY` syntax:

```sql
select ...
from   ...
ORDER BY something
OFFSET (:page_number - 1) * :page_size ROWS
FETCH FIRST :page_size ROWS ONLY;
```

---

Additionally, you have several correlated sub-queries such as:

```sql
select tk.TEM_LAHIR
from   KN.VW_KN_TK tk
where  tk.KODE_K = a.KODE_K and rownum=1
```

This will find the first matching row that the SQL engine happens to read from the datafile and is effectively finding a random row. If you want a specific row then you need an `ORDER BY` clause and you need to filter using `ROWNUM` **AFTER** the `ORDER BY` clause has been applied.

From Oracle 12, the correlated sub-query would be:

```sql
select tk.TEM_LAHIR
from   KN.VW_KN_TK tk
where  tk.KODE_K = a.KODE_K
ORDER BY something
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```